# Querying TFS Server incidents

Tags: tfs

I have been asked to look into is creating a Heat Map report in Power BI for managers to bring up and see all the tasks their staff is working on and the status (on schedule, approaching deadline, critical, etc.).

For the data sources, I am exploring the TFS databases. 
In the TFS database, which view or views would one be able to use to track work items?

I looked at the TFS data warehouse database and checked the DimWorkItem table.

I would need retrieve work items (such as Requirement, Change Request, Bug, etc.) as well as child tasks of this work item (work item type is “task”). 
Also, looking at the DimWorkItem view I can retrieve work items (such as Requirement, Change Request, Bug, etc.) as well as child tasks of this work item (work item type is “task”).

However, I do not see a column that identifies the parent of the task. For example, if the task with ID of 333 has a child with the task of 338 how would I be able to find the connection?

I do not see any child or parent columns in these incidents views.

Comment: What version of TFS do use?

Comment: We are using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: VS is not TFS )). Anyway, TFS_Warehouse database does not contain ipmTfsIncidentsV and ipmTfsPriorityIncidentsV views. I think that`s your (or your company) custom views. We can discuss tables and views of the out-of-box TFS_Warehouse DB.

Comment: You are right. I have updated the original post. Still I cannot see how child tasks are linked to parent work items in the database although the solution is in there somewhere.

Comment: They are linked in this table FactWorkItemLinkHistory.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use the vDimWorkItemTreeOverlay view as a data source. This is the sample query with one hierarchy level:

```
SELECT Parent.[WorkItem]
      ,Parent.[System_Id]
      ,Parent.[System_Title]
      ,Parent.[System_State]
      ,Parent.[System_WorkItemType]
      ,Parent.[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_TargetDate]
      ,Child.[WorkItem]
      ,Child.[System_Id]
      ,Child.[System_Title]
      ,Child.[System_State]
      ,Child.[System_Reason]
      ,Child.[System_WorkItemType]
      ,Child.[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_StartDate]
      ,Child.[Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_FinishDate]
  FROM [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[vDimWorkItemTreeOverlay] Parent
  LEFT JOIN [Tfs_Warehouse].[dbo].[vDimWorkItemTreeOverlay] Child ON Child.ParentWorkItemTreeSK = Parent.WorkItemTreeSK
  WHERE Parent.AreaTeamProject = 'DEV' AND Parent.System_IsDeleted = 0 AND Parent.System_WorkItemType in ('Bug', 'Product Backlog Item', 'Requirement') AND Child.System_WorkItemType = 'Task'
    AND Parent.WorkItemTreeSK = Parent.ParentWorkItemTreeSK AND Child.System_IsDeleted = 0
```

This is my result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Check this on test environment first**.

Also I`ve changed a query from standard tfs report with a work hierarchy. It works with one collection only. If you have several collections it may be updated:

```
DECLARE @ParentWorkItemLinkTypeSK int; 
SET @ParentWorkItemLinkTypeSK = (SELECT [WorkItemLinkTypeSK] FROM [DimWorkItemLinkType] WHERE [LinkID] < 0 AND [ReferenceName] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy');
DECLARE @ChildWorkItemLinkTypeSK int; 
SET @ChildWorkItemLinkTypeSK = (SELECT [WorkItemLinkTypeSK] FROM [DimWorkItemLinkType] WHERE [LinkID] > 0 AND [ReferenceName] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy');

DECLARE @ProjectName nvarchar(256);
SET @ProjectName = 'DEV'; -- set the team project name

DECLARE @RootNodeIDs TABLE (ID int);
INSERT @RootNodeIDs
    -- This is selecting all deliverable workitems
    SELECT cwi.[System_Id] AS ID FROM [CurrentWorkItemView] cwi
        WHERE cwi.[System_WorkItemType] IN ('Bug', 'Product Backlog Item', 'Requirement')
            AND cwi.[ProjectNodeName] = @ProjectName

EXCEPT
    -- This is selecting all workitems that have a parent and have not been deleted
    SELECT lh.SourceWorkItemID AS ID FROM FactWorkItemLinkHistory lh
        JOIN [CurrentWorkItemView] cwi ON cwi.System_Id = lh.TargetWorkItemID
        WHERE lh.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = @ParentWorkItemLinkTypeSK
            AND cwi.System_WorkItemType IN ('Bug', 'Product Backlog Item', 'Requirement')
            AND lh.RemovedDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '9999', 126)

DECLARE  @Hierarchy TABLE (ID int, ParentID int, [Level] int, [Path] nvarchar(4000));

WITH
Hierarchy (ID, ParentID, [Level], [Path]) AS
(
    SELECT ID, NULL as ParentID, 0 as [Level], CAST('/' + STR(ID) AS nvarchar(256)) as [Path]
    FROM @RootNodeIDs rootId 

UNION ALL

    SELECT flh.TargetWorkItemID as ID, Parent.ID, parent.Level + 1 as [Level], 
        CAST(parent.Path + '/' + STR(flh.TargetWorkItemID) AS nvarchar(256)) as [Path]
    FROM Hierarchy parent 
        JOIN FactWorkItemLinkHistory flh 
            ON flh.WorkItemLinkTypeSK = @ChildWorkItemLinkTypeSK
                AND flh.SourceWorkItemID = parent.ID
                AND flh.RemovedDate = CONVERT(DATETIME, '9999', 126)
        JOIN [CurrentWorkItemView] wi ON flh.TargetWorkItemID = wi.[System_ID]      


    WHERE parent.Path NOT LIKE CAST('%' + STR(flh.TargetWorkItemID) + '%' AS nvarchar(20)) AND parent.Level < 20 
)
INSERT @Hierarchy SELECT * FROM Hierarchy;
-- Hierarchy now contains all the Tasks and their ancestors that we're interested 

SELECT hierarchy.ID, ParentID, [Level], [Path], [ProjectNodeName] as Project, [System_State] as [State],
        [Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork] Remaining,
        [Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork] Completed,
        ([Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_RemainingWork] + [Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork]) Total,
        [System_WorkItemType] WIT,
        [System_Title] Title,
        [AreaPath] AreaPath,
        [IterationPath] IterationPath
    FROM @Hierarchy hierarchy
        INNER JOIN [CurrentWorkItemView] ON hierarchy.ID = [System_ID]
    ORDER BY [System_Id]
```

Result:

[image]